# How to elegantly define a generator producing an empty sequence

Tags: python-3.x

Because of the `yield` keyword, the Python compiler understands the method `g` in the code below as being a generator:

```
class B(A):
    def g(self):
        yield 1
```

However, I would like the `A` base class to provide a default implementation for `g` producing an empty sequence such as:

```
list(B().g())
--> [1]

list(A().g())
--> []
```

To achieve that, I define `A` as:

```
class A:
    def g(self):
        return; yield # do NOT remove the yield keyword:
                      # it is necessary for Python to
                      # understand `g` as a generator
```

It works, but I don't find that very elegant since, barring the comment, it is tempting to remove the unreachable `yield` statement.

So, is there a better, more pythonic way of defining a generator producing an empty sequence?

Comment: `return iter(())`?

Comment: Maybe @jorn. You may post that as an answer and we will see how other people vote

Comment: What do you mean *"maybe"*? This is the problem with *"elegantly"*, *"pythonic"*, and even *"better"* - what do you *mean*? Why does it matter how other people vote?

Comment: Actually, I'm not even sure it is absolutely necessary to define `g` as a generator. Maybe `return ()` will do the trick.